# Limits and asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits

We say that a function $f$ has an oblique asymptote if there are real numbers $k$ and $b$, where $k\ne0$ is non-zero such that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)-(kx+b)=0 $.

Or,

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists M>0$ such that if $x>M$, then $|f(x)-(kx+b)|<\epsilon$

This is straight-forward enough to show for functions with oblique asymptotes, but when considering functions that don't have oblique asymptotes, like the floor function, how can you conclusively show that they don't? Prove the negation?

(Edited to shorten question length)

Answer (score 0):

We can show first that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor/x=1$, so if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor -kx-b=0$ then $k=1$.

However, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ does not exist, since it oscillates between 0 and 1 when $x$ goes to the infinity. (You may use the definition of the limit: if there is a limit, then the range of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ would be included a small interval eventually, but it is not possible.)

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x-\lfloor x\rfloor-b$ also does not exist; in conclusion, no $k$ and $b$ satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor -kx-b=0$.

Comment: @woodenfield Sorry for late comment, I was sleeping after answering your quesiton. You may consider the limit of $(\lfloor x\rfloor -kx-b)/x$ for the first question. Moreover, the sign does not matter; if the limit of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ does not exist, so does $\lfloor x\rfloor -x$.

Comment: @woodenfield You can see that the limit belongs to $[-1,0]$, if exists. Take $\epsilon<1/3$. Could you see that there is $x>M$ such that $\lfloor x\rfloor -x$ does not belongs to $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$? (Observation: $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ is distant from either $0$ or $-1$.)

Comment: @woodenfield More formally, we can show that one of $0$ or $-1$ is not a member of $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ (what happens if both of them belongs to the interval?) If $0$ is not belongs to the interval, and $x$ a large real whose fractional part is near $0$, then $x$ is an example of what we want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track on the logic of the proof. This is how I'd continue:

The asymptote is a staight, and the floor function is like staircase. If you take a look at them on some interval $[n, n+1[$ ($n$ an integer), the floor function is constant, and the asymptote gains values from $kn+b$ to $kn+k+b$, so there's an increase of $k$ on this interval. Since the floor function is constant, there must be an $x$ on this interval so that $|f(x)-a(x)|>k/4$ ($f$ floor, $a$ asymptote). Here you can choose some other number than $k/4$, why I chose it was because you *would* like to choose $k/2$, but that doesn't play since $n+1$ isn't on the interval, so you have to choose some smaller number.

To fit this to your formulation, choose $\epsilon = k/4$, and for a $M\in\mathbb{R}$ choose an integer $n>M$, and so on.

EDIT: Here's how I would do it more rigorously:

Let's call the function $f$ and the asymptore $a(x)=kx+b$. We have to prove that there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ there is an $x>M$ for which $|f(x)-a(x)|\geqq\epsilon $.

Take $\epsilon = k/4$ and an arbitarry $M$ and an integer $n>M$, and look the interval $[n,n+1[$. It suffices to find the $x$ from this interval.

First try the left end point. If $|f(n)-a(n)|\geqq k/4$, the case is proved. If not, we know that $|f(n)-a(n)|< k/4$ and can
try a point very near the right end-point:
$$|a(n+1-\alpha )-f(n+1-\alpha )|=|a(n+1-\alpha )-f(n)|$$
$$\geqq ||a(n+1 -\alpha ) -a(n)|-|a(n)-f(n)||$$
$$= |k(1-\alpha ) -|(a(n)-f(n)||$$
$$\geqq k(1-\alpha ) - k/4 = \frac{3k}{4} -\alpha k>k/4$$
for example for $\alpha = 1/4.$

Here we used "the dark side" of the triangle inequality. Also I just noticed that I had assumed previously $k>0$, but it doesn't matter, if you take the absolute values in the right places.

Comment: Yes, I should have. Just noticed it too. it doesn't matter much however, since for cases $k<0$ the statement is obviously false (since the asymptote should increasing if it is anything). Or on the other hand, you can just put absolute values everywhere, works that way too.

I added somethin to the original answer, since the comments are akward for longer maths.